# SQL Join is changing values of my existing column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm attempting to use SQL to pull data from a database into a Jupyter (python) notebook and work with it there. I have a query that pulls the yearweek of flight's upload date, and counts the number of flights in that yearweek. Finally, it groups the results by the yearweek of upload date:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(d.upload_date), COUNT(f.id)
FROM apps_flight f
LEFT JOIN apps_enginedatafile d ON d.id=f.import_file_id
WHERE f.global_duplicate = 0
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(d.upload_date)
```

I want to count number of subscribers (located in another table) from each yearweek to compare them to count of flights. So I'm trying to join said table by adding:

```
LEFT JOIN apps_subscription s ON s.basesubscription_ptr_id = f.id
```

But, when I do this, the counts of my flight values change!
The first few counts for the original query look like:

[327, 605, 78, 5768, 9716, 9686, 7902, 3699, 3323, 6081, 4966, 3456, 3181, 2749, 4577, 3157, 1792, 1806, ...]

After joining the table, it becomes:

[327, 738, 78, 8854, 17418, 16156, 13921, 7536, 5380, 10040, 7559, 5461, 6323, 6412, 6702, 5433, 2924, ...]

I'm not sure what's happening here. Perhaps the join is creating duplicate rows? The data set is very large, and takes about 30 minutes to run the query. Adding a LIMIT doesn't seem to speed it up, so as you can imagine, testing takes a little while. (If I'm oblivious to another way to speed up the query aside from a LIMIT, feel free to make me aware)!

Thanks for any info.

Comment: what's the purpose of the join?

Comment: The `JOIN` is not one to one with rows in `f`.  If more than one row in the joined table matches a specific `f.id`, that row in `f` is now in the result N times, once for each match, changing the aggregate result.  This is normal join behavior.

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE I forgot to include it in the post, I'll edit it. I'm trying to join this new table to then count the number of subscribers in each yearweek, to compare it to number of flights in each yearweek. The number of subscribers is found in the table I'm trying to join.

Comment: count before joining

Comment: 30 minutes? How large are we talking about here? More than 1 million rows for each table?

Comment: if you want help optimizing your query, you should open a new question, and include (as text) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables in the query and output of `explain select ...` for your query

Comment: it would have been helpful if you had included your full new query; it isn't clear what you are actually doing to count the subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Simply join two aggregate count queries. Below assumes same structure including columns names. (Adjust `upload_date` to actual date/time column in `apps_subscription`.)

```sql
WITH agg_flights AS (
    SELECT YEARWEEK(d.upload_date) AS year_week, 
           COUNT(f.id) AS flight_counts
    FROM apps_flight f
    LEFT JOIN apps_enginedatafile d  
         ON d.id = f.import_file_id
    WHERE f.global_duplicate = 0
    GROUP BY YEARWEEK(d.upload_date)
), agg_subs AS (
    SELECT YEARWEEK(s.upload_date) AS year_week,  -- ADJUST date/time variable
           COUNT(f.id) AS subscriber_counts
    FROM apps_flight f
    LEFT JOIN apps_subscription s 
         ON s.basesubscription_ptr_id = f.id
    WHERE f.global_duplicate = 0
    GROUP BY YEARWEEK(s.upload_date)              -- ADJUST date/time variable
)

SELECT f.year_week, 
       f.flight_counts,
       s.subscriber_counts
FROM agg_flights f
INNER JOIN agg_subs s
  ON f.year_week = s.year_week
```

Answer (score 0):

Joins create combined rows of all the tables joined.  So your join between f and d will have multiple rows (before the group by) for a single flight if that flight has more than one import_file_id value, and the join on s will add multiple rows if a flight has more than one subscription.  And COUNT operates on the result of the joins, not on the f table before the join.

In this case, the easy fix is to just use `COUNT(DISTINCT f.id)` instead of `COUNT(f.id)`, so each flight is only counted once per yearweek.